# Is it possible to event.target.matches('.class-1.class-2' > .class-3')

Tags: javascript

Basically I want to do something like this:

```
<my-root-element id="myID">
    <button id="some-id">Occupy The Universe</button>
    <div id="x" class="class-1 class-1a">
        <div id="y" class="class-3">
        <p>Rabit hole</p>
    </div>
</div>
</my-root-element>

let rootEl = document.getElementById(myID);
rootEl.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target && e.target.matches('button#some-id')) {
        console.log("Did something nasty");
    } else if (e.target && e.target.matches('.class-1.class-1a') || e.target && e.target.matches('.class-1.class-1a > .class-3')) {
        console.log("Was there");
    }
});
```

It looks for me that class nesting is not working, but maybe I'm missing something? I would like to do this in one IF as both things do the same thing. It looks like `querySelector` supports nested classes, but can't figure out, how to implement it there.

Comment: Well your code will make the tests on the element, but without knowing what your HTML actually looks like it's impossible to say whether those selectors are correct or not.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want to do. You may want to try wrapping your logical conditions in parentheses; i.e. `if ((e.target && e.target.matches('.class-1.class-1a')) || (e.target && e.target.matches('.class-1.class-1a > .class-3'))) {`

Comment: @HereticMonkey that will not make any difference at all; that's already how the expression will be parsed because `&&` binds more tightly than `||`.

Comment: @Pointy I didn't say it would make a difference, I just suggested they may want to. Makes things easier to read.

Comment: Well what would help would be to make the `e.target` test just once and then parenthesize the `||` subexpression. However all of that is irrelevant if the selectors are incorrect anyway :)

Comment: Works on my FF (tested with question title element on this page). First, we have to know what `e.target` actually is.

Comment: I edited example. Basically i need to do this, because `#y` are smaller than `#x`. No matter user clicks on `x` or `y` i need to do the same thing. Currently only first case returns `Was there`.

Comment: And it is important to to use nested selector because this event should not be executed if there is no `class-1a` for the root element.

Comment: I think there is something, that `target.matches` watch only clicked element and can access classes only down to the element chain and he can't go level upper.

Comment: I suppose that the real target of the click event is the `p` element nested inside the   `.class-1.class-2' > .class-3` element. That is why it doesn't match.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like simple styling for `#x` helped. An no more needed that `||` part.

```
> * {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me is given below
Now when I click on **Image** or **Profile** button text it appears and toggle

```
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function userProfile() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
  }
  
  // Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
  window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!event.target.matches(['.dropbtn', '.profile'])) {
      var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
        var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
        if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
          openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another short and nice solution that I've used is:

```
$(document).on('click', 'body, .action-button', function(e) {
        var root = e.target.closest('.node-actions')
        if(e.target.className !== 'action-button'){                
            $(".actions-list").fadeOut(); // Close all, no matter who is root
        } else {
            $(root).find(".actions-list").fadeIn(); // Fade in only for one in that root
        }
    });
```

This example looks for closest element, no need for loops. Not exact solution for your problem but could give you idea.